# ASP.Net Core Bearer Authentication + flutter client

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core, bearer-token, asp.net-authentication, flutter-http

I have a problem with Bearer Authentication in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Api project.

I configured authentication like that:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = AuthHelper.Issuer,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidAudience = AuthHelper.Audience,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = AuthHelper.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    };

                });
```

Also, I added `[Authorize]` attribute in my controller and `app.UseAuthorization();` in Configure method.

I configured the request in Postman. I tried to configure authorization in the "Authorization" tab and manual way (adding "Authorization" header). The same result: I get the correct answer without any errors.

However, when I send the request from my flutter app, I get a "404 Not Found" error.

Get request from flutter app:

```
Map<String, String> authHeaders = <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $authToken'
  };
    final response = await http.get(_url, headers: authHeaders);
```

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know what the problem is.
My controller still uses Cookies authentication method (not bearer).

**Solution:** Replace `[Authorize]` by `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

**Why request from Postman works properly?**

Postman sets cookies and remembers Cookies for other requests.
So when I tested the signin controller, Postman added `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` cookie to own collection.